# Can JavaScript listen for state changes from a QuickTime object embedded in a web page?

Tags: javascript, events, audio, streaming, quicktime

I'm attempting to control a QuickTime object that I have embedded into a webpage using JavaScript, and want to listen to and react to the DOM events that the object throws. Apple has [published a tutorial on the matter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_JavaScript/bQTScripting_JavaScri_Document/QuickTimeandJavaScri.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001526-CH001-SW5) that doesn't seem to work at all. The code that I made using their documentation is as follows:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
     $('#plugin').html( QT_GenerateOBJECTText( 'http://streaming1.wecreate.com:443/ckkw_kfun.mp3' , '300', '300', '', 'obj#ID', 'qt', 'emb#ID', 'qt', 'emb#NAME', 'qt', 'postdomevents', 'true', 'EnableJavaScript', 'true', 'autoplay', 'true' ) );
    qt = document.getElementById('qt');
    if(!qt ) {
        alert("Couldn't get QT Handle");
     }
     RegisterListeners();
});

function myAddListener(obj, evt, handler, captures) {
     if ( document.addEventListener )
          obj.addEventListener(evt, handler, captures);
     else
          obj.attachEvent('on' + evt, handler);
}
function RegisterListener(eventName, objID, embedID, listenerFcn) {
     var obj = document.getElementById(objID);
     if(!obj )
          obj = document.getElementById(embedID);
     if(obj)
          myAddListener(obj, eventName, listenerFcn, false);
}
function RegisterListeners() {
     RegisterListener('qt_begin', 'qt', 'qt', qtStateChanged);
     RegisterListener('qt_play', 'qt', 'qt', qtStateChanged);
     RegisterListener('qt_pause', 'qt', 'qt', qtStateChanged);
}
function qtStateChanged() {
    alert("State Changed!");
}
```

That code isn't as clean as it could be - I should be carrying the qt object through it all, but I wanted to leave it as close to Apple's demo code as possible.

In firefox, the code successfully loads the QuickTime object and begins playing the stream (as per the autoplay option), but I don't receive a single call to qtStateChanged() even though I have set the postdomevents and enablejavascript parameters set on the QuickTime object.

In Chrome, I get the QuickTime logo, but no audio or controls. The object reports the qt_begin event, and I get a JavaScript alert. In IE6 (we still have some technologically backward customers), the player loads, but the autoplay option doesnt work, and the JavaScript callbacks don't work at all.

I've also tried to control the player from JavaScript, again to no avail. The following are three different jQuery statements that attempt to pause the player. None of them work in any of the three browsers that I've tested in:

```
<p onclick="JavaScript:$(qt).Pause();">Suck it, Trebek</p>
<p onclick="JavaScript:$('#qt').Pause();">Suck it again, Trebek</p>
<p onclick="JavaScript:$('#plugin').Pause();">Suck it a third, Trebek</p>
```

Does anybody have any insight on this communication between JavaScript and QuickTime? A tutorial that wasn't written 10 years ago would be a great boon.

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer - but I've found in dealing with Quicktime and Windows Media, that the plugins act very differently depending on which browser and version of browser.  Meaning - some commands will work with some plugins, and some won't.  Very frustrating, but you are not alone.

Comment: I found this while doing similar work with the Windows Media Player plugin. Luckily, I was able to find a post here on Stack Overflow that provided what seems to be a working cross-browser solution.
I have no problem limiting the solution to one or more browsers. Ideally, it would work in anything that is not IE, since I can use WMP for that.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use HTML5 video?  <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video> This seems like it would be easier to interface with and you could use WebM for Chrome & Firefox 4 and then use H.264 for IE9 and Safari.

Comment: RegisterListener seems to be assuming that it will get the reference to the movie - and I wonder what is the difference betweenbut has no error handling. Perhaps you could have an else clause after the last if, to make sure that obj is meaningful?

Answer (score 1):

QuickTime object embedded is not a standard HTML element, it working through browser plugin interface, and it was made by a 3rd party provider then not all browser have it. It has been support very poor API to interactive. As far as I known you can not listen for state changes event from QuickTime object because of it is not stable enough and not available through almost famous browsers. Even if you luckily with Safari then it will simply won't work on IE, Firefox, Opera ...

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

AC_QuickTime.js is a total pain.

I came to the conclusion that Events just don't work in IE.

There where other weird effects I should perhaps mention.

- Make sure you have the latest version from [this link](http://www.apple.com/library/quicktime/scripts/ac_quicktime.js). I started with a different version which did not work at all.
- AC_QuickTime.js adds a event source object into the dom tree on IE.
  The problem with that is that it will steal 16 pixels ontop of the
  player frame.

Turn *txt = _QTGenerateBehavior() + txt;* into *txt = txt + _QTGenerateBehavior();* in AC_QuickTime.js to move that bastard to the bottom.

Here some sample code for good measure.
Some variables are undefined since this code is part of a closure.
Remember. **This code still does not work on IE.** (Tested IE 8)

```
element.innerHTML = QT_GenerateOBJECTText(
  'sample_mpeg4.mp4', set_c.width, set_c.height + 16, '',
  'obj#id'  , element.id + 'PlayerElement',
  'emb#NAME', element.id + 'PlayerElement' ,
  'emb#id'  , element.id + 'EmbPlayerElement' ,
  'scale' , 'tofit' , 'AUTOPLAY', 'True', 'CONTROLLER', 'True',
  'EnableJavaScript', 'True', 'postdomevents', 'True',
  'qtsrc', url);
var try_register = 5;
var event_handler = function(ev){
  console.log("Event! " + ev.type);
};
var callback = function(){
  try_register--;
  console.log("Register Event");
  var obj = document.getElementById(element.id + 'PlayerElement');
  if(obj){
    if(document.addEventListener){
      obj.addEventListener('qt_error', event_handler, false);
      obj.addEventListener('qt_pause', event_handler, false);
      obj.addEventListener('qt_stalled', event_handler, false);
      obj.addEventListener('qt_ended', event_handler, false);
    } else {
      // IE
      obj.attachEvent('onqt_error', event_handler);
      obj.attachEvent('onqt_pause', event_handler);
      obj.attachEvent('onqt_stalled', event_handler);
      obj.attachEvent('onqt_ended', event_handler);
    }
  } else {
    if(try_register > 0)
      setTimeout(callback, 250);
  }
};
setTimeout(callback, 250);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, update to my comments above. In my tests, this is simply broken. Deafening silence on the quicktime-users mailing list when I asked. I am certain it's a bug: Events are not triggered by QuickTime movies any more.